# Применить класс к элементу при изменении высоты другого элемента

Tags: jquery, css

Необходимо применить класс к меню, если элементы предшествующего ему блока, перестают помещаться в одну строку:

```css
.wrapper {
  background: #ccc;
}
header {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 300px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.top-block > div {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.top-block:after,
.menu:after{
  content:"";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #65a;
}
.cart {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #00f;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 50px;
  background: #f00;
  color: #fff;
}

.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}

.static-menu {
  position: static;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <div class="top-block">
      <div class="logo">logo</div>
      <div class="tel">+25253546</div>
      <div class="cart"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li>link1</li>
        <li>link2</li>
        <li>link3</li>
        <li>link4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
 </div>
```

Т.е. мне нужно при уменьшении ширины окна, когда изменится высота верхнего блока, добавить к меню класс static-menu
https://jsfiddle.net/q4swqdup/

Comment: а зачем это делать таким тяжелым способом. Как же @media в СSS?

Comment: Может я немного мудрено сформулировал - класс нужно применить только когда содержимое верхнего блока перестанет помещаться в строку, а заранее мы не можем знать на какой ширине экрана это произойдет

Comment: Ну, на самом деле можем. Ведь мы туда вставляем контент. Что касательно динамических вещей, посмотрите в сторону MutationObserver